# Norm of the operator and Riesz-Markov-Kakutani measure - example functional

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $X = C[0,1]$ with supremum norm. Define linear functional:
> $$
> \varphi(f) = \int_0^1f(x)cos(\pi x)dx - f(\frac{1}{2})
> $$
> Show that $\varphi$ is bounded and compute its norm. Using the Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem give the complex measure that is associated with that functional.

---

My attempt was:

Bounded:
$$
\|\varphi\| = \sup_{\|f\|_{\infty}=1}|\varphi(f)| = \sup_{\|f\|_{\infty}=1}|\int_0^1f(x)cos(\pi x)dx - f(\frac{1}{2})| = \\
\leq \sup_{\|f\|_{\infty}=1}\int_0^1|f(x)cos(\pi x)|dx + |f(\frac{1}{2})| \\
\leq \sup_{\|f\|_{\infty}=1}\|f\|_{\infty}\int_0^1|cos(\pi x)|dx + \|f\|_{\infty} \leq 1 + 1 = 2
$$
Where last equation is due to cosine function being bounded by 1.

Now the norm, letting $f = 2$ (constant):
$$
\|\varphi(f)\| = |2\int_0^1cos(\pi x) - 2| = |0 - 2| = 2
$$
so the norm (taking the bound into account) is equal to 2.

Lastly, the measure seems to be:
$$
\mu(A) = \cos{(\pi x)}d\lambda(A) - \delta_{\frac{1}{2}}(A)
$$
because then
$$
\int_0^1fd\mu = \int_0^1fd\cos{(\pi x)}- \delta_{\frac{1}{2}} = \int_0^1f(x)cos(\pi x)dx - f(\frac{1}{2})
$$

It was an exam task and I only got half of the points. Could anyone show me the correct answer? I suppose my measure is wrong ($\lambda(A)$ doesn't make much sense) but I didn't have better ideas that time.

Comment: Can you state this Riesz-Markov-Kakutani theorem, or at least point to somewhere where it is stated? thanks

Comment: Oh, it must be the statement that the dual of $C([0,1])$ is the space of complex measures on $[0, 1]$

Comment: Basically this one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz–Markov–Kakutani_representation_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out:

- Bound can be made tighter:

$$
|\int_0^1f(x)\cos(\pi x)dx - f(\frac{1}{2})| \leq \|f\|_{\infty}\frac{2}{\pi} + \|f\|_{\infty} \implies \sup_{\|f\|_{\infty}=1} \varphi(f) \leq \frac{2}{\pi}+1
$$

- Proper measure is:

$$
\mu(A) = \int_A\cos{\pi x}dx - \delta_\frac{1}{2}(A)
$$

- using Riesz-Markov-Kakutani measure we know that the norm of the functional equals to the variation of the measure

$$
|\mu|(X) = \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\cos{\pi x}dx + \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1-\cos{\pi x}dx + 1 = \frac{2}{\pi} + 1 = \|\varphi\|
$$

Comment: So, where is the mistake in your computation above? Isn’t $\varphi(2)=2$? Because the measure you gave is essentially correct. What penalized you must have something to do with the norm of $\varphi$.

Comment: I'm also not sure. My bound was correct but it could have been made smaller(I limited $\int_0^1|\cos{\pi x}|dx$ by 1 while in fact it can be easily calculated and equals $\frac{2}{\pi} < 1$). I don't see however, why $\| \varphi(f) \|$ where $f = 2$ is not 2.

Comment: Oh, maybe because $\| \varphi(f) \| = 2$ but $\|f \| \neq 1$.

Comment: Yes, that’s it. Therefore, you only gave an estimate for the norm of $\varphi$, you did not compute its exact value. That’s good; I don’t think you will be doing the same mistake again, now. :-) I also still remember similar mistakes I did as a student. Learning through error is the best.